# How to convert model data objects array to dataProvider

Tags: php, model, yii, dataprovider

Suppose I have model `User` which have many to many relation to itself named as `friends`.
so `$user->friends` (or `$model->friends` in view) gives me an array of `User` objects. I wanted to display the friends as gridview. But `CGridView` data as `dataProvider` object. Googling for it found the way to convert array of model objects to `dataProvider` object as given below.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'gridUser',
    'dataProvider' => new CArrayDataProvider($model->friends, array()),
));
```

Now using this I get an error

> Property "User.id" is not defined.

UPDATE

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
         'friends' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'User', 'friendship(user_id, friend_id)'),
    );
}
```

Comment: adding how you defined relation and how two models relate (PK and FK) is crucial to getting an answer!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I use two stage building the provider shown below. But I  found that it gives you trouble in terms of Pagination. I have not bothered to resolve that problem since am doing other things

```
$dataProvider =  new CArrayDataProvider('User');
$dataProvider->setData($model->friends);
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'gridUser',
    'dataProvider' =>$dataProvider,
));
```

That being said, your code should work (see the example below from API docs). I suspect there is wrong attribute in your relations than the provided code. Re-check the relation definition if it is ok

From Yii docs:

```
$rawData=Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM tbl_user')->queryAll();
// or using: $rawData=User::model()->findAll(); <--this better represents your question
$dataProvider=new CArrayDataProvider($rawData, array(
    'id'=>'user',
    'sort'=>array(
        'attributes'=>array(
             'id', 'username', 'email',
        ),
    ),
    'pagination'=>array(
        'pageSize'=>10,
    ),
));
```

Comment: got the exact thing i was searching, anyways thanks dude. thumbs up to your answer too.

Comment: the exact answer that i was searching is given below. please check it and upvote if its useful

Comment: Great that I was of help :)

Comment: Please check if the below given answer is correct or not. I got the required result from that. I just want to know if its a better answer or not

Comment: its nice and efficient solution I can think of. So no need to worry!

Comment: How to get rid of 'Displaying 1-2 of 6 results.' like text that shows up above the grid?

Answer (score 13):

Got it :) , i can use `CActiveDataProvider` instead of `CArrayDataProvider` as given below

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'gridUser',
    'dataProvider' => new CActiveDataProvider('User', array(
            'data'=>$model->friends,
    )),
    //...... columns display list.....
));
```

Anyways thanks for the reply @Stefano

Comment: this is a better answer, as it enables CGridView to fetch grid headers from the CModel...