# yii use a model related function in a view

Tags: methods, yii, model, get

I have no reputation to comment on a question, so I am making a new one. But my question is related to another question: [How to convert model data objects array to dataProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134653/how-to-convert-model-data-objects-array-to-dataprovider/)

So.... if you read the question, my doubt is:

I need to ask for help to a new thing that this subject rises. I would like to get a function result as the data of a column, but this function is inside the Friend object. Its not possible to do:

```
array(
    'name'=>$model->friends->getAttributeLabel('column_of_friend_model'),
    'value'=> $model->friends->takeDataFromFriendModelThatIsActuallyInOtherModel(),
),
```

Can someone please help!? Thanks a lot!

Comment: have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330040/extract-data-from-relations?rq=1